# How do I add ROUND function to formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have following formula, and need it to round to two decimal places

```
=IF(ISBLANK(N2),"",10/(N-1))
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(N2), "", ROUND(10/(N2-1), 2))
```

Comment: You can also use ROUNDUP or ROUNDDOWN in place of just ROUND if you need it to go in a specific direction.

Answer (score 0):

Could format the cell to number, two decimal places right click cell, format,number,two dp.

There is a round function but not sure how to get it into that formula.